# Entity framework organizing models

Tags: entity-framework

I am a beginner with Entity Framework and after some time working with EF I am stuck with an organizational issue.

Not really sure is it better to map entire database (objects that I would use) to one model, or split it to different models (group objects to models base on class needs).

First approach sound like a easy one, but I have doubts are there any performance issues on large number of object, or would it take to long to update model for entire db.

Second approach could let me end up using same objects in different models, and how would that affect updating models?

Comment: Unless you have few hundreds of tables, there should be no need to split. The amount of data in the database doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a single model and only move away from that if you encounter some sort of problem in terms of needing to separate it out (e.g. if you want to promote some sort of reuse of different parts in different modules or applications). Even then, there is probably not a need to do the separation.

There is no real penalty for having a large model of your entire database with EF. The framework does a good job of optimizing before runtime (much of this is optimized at "configuration runtime"). At "transaction runtime", you shouldn't see performance issues based on the number of tables in the database.

If there are any relationships that otherwise would have to be maintained across multiple models, and you went with multiple models, you're basically opening yourself to hassles. If your physical data model is partitioned into separate physical schemas and there are no transactional relationships to be maintained, then multiple models would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "Model", by EF allows you specify schema on Class definition, that will allow you group tables into different groups based on schema. For example, you can group all the look up tables which has static data into a "Lookup" schema, and the other tables in a "Data" schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you have distinct parts of your application, so a lot of relations between some tables (let's call this a `part` for lack of a better word) with no relations to all the other tables (so all other parts), and you have a lot of tables (more than 100 by part), I would definitely advice to create multiple `contexts`.

If you have a few tables or they are all very tightly related, I would definitely keep them together in a single context.